# How to prove the limit definitions of big O big Theta and big Omega

Tags: limits, asymptotics

So far I learned:

> $O(f(n)) := {g : Z≥0 → R : ∃c, n0 > 0∀n ≥ n0 : |g(n)| ≤ c · |f(n)|}$
>   $Ω(f(n)) := {g : Z≥0 → R : ∃c, n0 > 0∀n ≥ n0 : |f(n)| ≤ c · |g(n)|}$
>   $Θ(f(n)) := {g : Z≥0 → R : ∃c1,2, n0 > 0∀n ≥ n0 : c1 · |f(n)| ≤ |g(n)|
>  ≤ c2 · |f(n)|}$

But on Wikipedia I found out that there are also other definitions of those notations (by limits).

E.g. $\limsup_{x \to a} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right| < \infty$ for $f \in \mathcal{O}(g)$. To be allowed using those definitions I need to prove them. But I can't find the proof online and I'm not able to prove it by myself. Do you know a way?

Comment: "how to proof" -> "How to prove"

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you, edited

Comment: Your definitions are exactly those limit definitions with $\limsup_{n \to \infty}$. $O,\Omega,\Theta$ and $o$ can also be used with finite limits on continuous domains.

Comment: @Ian may my problem is that I can't find the right definition of limitis then... Can you show me the one you know?

Comment: Which case are you trying to understand, the $n \to \infty$ case or the $x \to a$ case?

Comment: @Ian I guess $x \to \infty$ is enough for me, however if I understand the $x \to a$ I should understand $x \to \infty$ aswell, shouldn't I?

Comment: The two definitions just look significantly different when you expand them out, that's all. Look up a definition of limits at infinity, it should look a lot like your definitions. It becomes actually your definitions when you switch from $\lim$ to $\limsup$.

Comment: @Ian I will definetly check out the lim sup definitions then. However I just did the same thing for the lim now and came up with this: 
$lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = c$ is defined as $∀ \varepsilon > 0 ∃ n_0 \le n: |f(n)-c| < \varepsilon $ is this right? Because if it is I can't find a way to show that it's equal to the definition up there. (I will try the lim sup now...)

Comment: That's mostly right, except it is $(\exists n_0)(\forall n \geq n_0)$. It's not quite the same; you need the limsup to show it's actually the same. The desired definition is basically "the limit is less than or equal to $c$" except without the assumption that the limit actually exists, or in other words "all limit points are less than or equal to $c$".

Comment: @Ian Sorry, but I still can't find a definition of lim sup like that. I just found other ones that I don't understand to be honest.

Comment: The limsup is the smallest real number $s$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $x_n<s+\epsilon$, or $\infty$ if no such number exists. Thus if the limsup is less than some real number $r$ then there exists $N$ such that if $n \geq N$ then $x_n<r$. The limsup is less than $\infty$ if some such real number $r$ exists, i.e. if the sequence is bounded above.

Comment: @Ian Would there be a difference in defining $1>ϵ>0$ instead of just $ϵ>0$?

Comment: @user387499 The two are equivalent.

Comment: @Ian I think I've got a solution then. **THANK YOU!**